# ¿Por qué decimos "por cierto" para indicar añadidura?

Tags: modismos, expresiones

La palabra "cierto" tiene distintos significados:

> [**cierto, ta**](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=VREkTc42hDXX2Bo3Bqdc)
>   (Del lat. certus).
>   1. adj. Conocido como verdadero, seguro, indubitable.
>   2. adj. U. precediendo inmediatamente al sustantivo en sentido indeterminado. Cierto lugar. Cierta noche.
>   3. adj. Dicho de un perro: Que da señas ciertas de la caza, y que con seguridad la levanta.
>   4. adj. Sabedor, seguro de la verdad de algún hecho.
>   5. adj. ant. certero.
>   6. adj. germ. fullero.
>   ¶ MORF. sup. irreg. certísimo.
>   7. adv. afirm. ciertamente.

Más adelante vemos en la sección de expresiones:

> **por cierto**.
>   1. loc. adv. Ciertamente, a la verdad.
>   2. loc. adv. A propósito, viniendo al caso de lo que se dice.

Y esta es la que me interesa: ¿cuál es el origen de decir "por cierto" para añadir algo? Por ejemplo en estos casos:

> Nos vemos esta tarde. Por cierto, acuérdate de traer el libro que te
>   dejé.
>
> ¿Cómo está tu hija? Por cierto, mi hermana me dio recuerdos para ti.

Comment: En portugués decimos «é verdade» (‘es verdad’) con la misma finalidad. ¿Cómo está tu hija? ‘Es verdad’, mi hermana me dio recuerdos para ti. Quizá por la misma razón?

Comment: @Jacinto pues seguramente. Tal y como comentaba Rodrigo en su respuesta, parece tener su origen en el uso de _por casualidad_. De todos modos, abro una recompensa (*bounty*) para ver si obtenemos más información al respecto. ¡Gracias por reabrir el debate!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Según recuerdo, viene de **por acierto**. No he encontrado fuentes que lo confirmen, pero esta respuesta te puede servir de base.

La palabra *acierto* tiene la misma raíz de *cierto*, *certeza* y *cerciorar* (significa algo así como "dar en el blanco"), pero también derivó hace tiempo a "casualidad" o "coincidencia". En mi caso en Chile no uso ni he escuchado esa acepción.

Entonces, en:

> Nos vemos esta tarde. Por cierto, acuérdate de traer el libro que te dejé.

la expresión *por cierto* significaría "por casualidad nuestra conversación  me hizo recordar que me debes un libro". O "qué acierto estar hablando de esto, porque ahora recuerdo que me debes un libro".

Answer (score 1):

En cuanto al origen, he encontrado que "pro explorato habere" derivó en "tener por cierto que"  [Locuciones + Orígenes](http://www.monografias.com/trabajos74/locuciones-latinas-usuales/Locuciones-latinas-usuales6.shtml). Y ahora me pregunto si "por cierto" es la siguiente derivación o simplemente está a la deriva (de origen incierto).

En cualquier caso: "una locución es, en gramática, el grupo estable de dos o más palabras que funciona como una unidad léxica con significado propio, no derivado del literal de las palabras que lo forman" [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locuci%C3%B3n). Lo cual complica teorizar sobre el origen de dicha locución.

Tengo un problema con "A propósito, viniendo al caso de lo que se dice" como definición de "por cierto" siendo este último también utilizado para cambiar de tema en una conversación como en el ejemplo de esta pregunta:

- ¿Cómo está tu hija? Por cierto, mi hermana me dio recuerdos para ti

Para mi es una definición incompleta o negligente que puede dar lugar a la ambiguedad.

Espero que todo esto haya servido de ayuda, un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Por intuición: en portugués tiene el sentido de *ciertamente*, que debió ser el sentido original en castellano. Sucede que en muchas frases de este tipo puede alcanzar un sentido de causalidad y tal vez tuviese lugar una deriva semántica.